# Ajax-like loading, and too many getchars

Tags: c

I got two questions:

In ajax, it is possible to add some gif while the server is doing something behind the scenes. Is it possible to write something to the console like "executing..." while it's doing something, and then delete it and throw expected results?

The second question, maybe more realistic, is - in the `main()` function I used two `scanf()` methods. After that I had to use two `getchar()`'s at the end to stop the console. Why is that and how to deal with it?

Comment: These two questions are so unrelated it is best to ask them in two separate questions

Comment: Unfortunately I believe I'd have to wait 24h before asking the second one.

Comment: 1. do something like `printf("executing...\r");` to erase just print something again (or a lot of spaces). 2. `scanf` doesn't "eat" symbol "\n", so, first `getchar` just returns last "\n".

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

1. do something like printf("executing...\r"); to erase just print something again (or a lot of spaces).
2. scanf doesn't "eat" symbol "\n", so, first getchar just returns last "\n".

–  Eddy_Em

Answer (score -1):

for question one: you should make the request and after the $.ajax call, do what you wanna to. cause at tha time ajax will be loading(since it's async).

Something like this:

function foo(){
   $.ajax(url, data, callback);
   DoYourStuff();
}

question two: you should use fflush(stdin); to clean the buffer.
Maybe the '\n' key was hold and when you used getchar it was released.

Comment: The OP is not asking about how to do something in Ajax.  Also, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined.  Also see http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html and http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: Wait, the first question was about doing this in C, ajax was just an example.

Comment: No he's asking if it's possible. Therefore how to do it. And by showing him an example i'm saying that it's possible.

Comment: No, his sentence "In Ajax, it is possible..." is a statement, not a question.  He's using Ajax as an example for something he wants to do in C *as he explained in his comment to this answer*.

Comment: Oh, misunderstood. Sorry. Thought he said: "Is it", not "it is".